# _.where with RegExp in object return empty lodash

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

I am creating a filter for a JSON object to filter the result depending on the value of the field.

if we have the object below:

```
var vo = [{
  "programName": "Tesco.com",
   "code": "FFCLUB10",
   "updateDate": "1424270164689"
},
{
   "id": 160320,
   "programId": 239597,
   "programName": "Panda Security UK"
}];
```

Using the following code I want to filter the object and just have the one that programName starts with T:

```
Voucher = _.where(vo, { 'programName': new RegExp('^' + '[T]', 'i')});
```

However I have an empty object as a result, I am using the lodash module.
Could you give me some lights on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using find

```
Voucher = _.find(vo, function (item) {
   return item.programName.match(new RegExp('^' + '[' + req.query.alphabet + ']', 'i'));
});
```

jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tz279fv0/

Comment: Hello again :), however the return value is an array and I expect and object should I cast the result?

Comment: Lodash find will return the element found - https://lodash.com/docs#find. The only way it would return an array is if the element found is an array

Comment: As a note: If you want to return an array you could replace `find` with `filter` in the code above.